# DynamoDB vs S3 flat files?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, parquet, bigdata, nosql

I am storing terabytes of click stream type user event data. It needs to be indexed or partitioned by date so that a narrow date range can be queried reasonably quickly. I want to be able to run aggregation jobs and queries on this. I would expect to use Spark in Amazon EMR or something similar.

One option is S3 flat files partitioned by day+hour like:

```
s3://my-bucket/20160503_00/data.txt
s3://my-bucket/20160503_01/data.txt
s3://my-bucket/20160503_02/data.txt
```

I would more likely use Parquet columnar storage rather than raw text like:

```
s3://my-bucket/20160503_00/data.parquet
s3://my-bucket/20160503_01/data.parquet
s3://my-bucket/20160503_02/data.parquet
```

Another option is full Amazon DynamoDB?

What are the pros/cons of each?

Comment: not sure SO is the best source of pro/con - but:   if you're using s3, store your content compressed to save significant space and IO cycles (since you're effectively storing text, it's going to compress well.)    also, keep your record-to-file ratio low (ie, not 1 record per second per file, aggregate them to a minute's worth per file, or whatever is apropos - if possible).    when I did something like this ages ago, we'd sync to s3 every second, but come back every 5 minutes and aggregate the per-second data into larger chunks..)

Answer (score 0):

You can stream data from AWS Kinesis through [AWS Kinesis Firehose](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html) to buffer your data and save it to S3 in the smaller of [128MB or 15 minute chunks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-create.html#console-to-s3). Firehose will automatically place your chunks in subfolders that enable the range-based lookup you require.